# JTA transaction timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jta

If JTA transaction is configured or programmatically set a timeout value, when time reachs, should TransactionManager call rollback method on every XAResource which participate the tx? Or resource manager just rollback the transaction branch itself, since TXManager should has notified it thu XAResource.setTransactionTimeout?

In other words, who should count the time and schedule the rollback, TransactionManager/ individual ResourceManager, or both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is the TransactionManager. If you follow this link https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-2565 which says in JBOSS,

if a timeout is associated with a transaction when a resource is enlisted, the same timeout is set on the XAResource.